# symfony2: command runs out of memory

Tags: php, symfony

I am developing a symfony2 application (more specifically I am using symfony 2.7.1).

I created a command to take information from a database, elaborate it, and transfer it to the new database.

It goes more or less like this:

```
  // init stuff
    $count = 0;

    while ( ( $res = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM mytable LIMIT ".$count*100 .", ".(++$count)*100) ) && (mysqli_num_rows($res) > 0 ) )
    {

        while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res))
        {
            $my_variable_1 = new myClass1();
            $my_variable_2 = new myClass2();
            $my_variable_3 = new myClass3();

            $my_variable_1 -> setFieldA( $my_variable_2 );
            $my_variable_1 -> setFieldB( $my_variable_3 );

            $my_variable_1 -> setField01               ($row['field_01']);
            $my_variable_1 -> setField02               ($row['field_02']);
            $my_variable_1 -> setField03               ($row['field_03']);
            $my_variable_1 -> setField04               ($row['field_04']);
            $my_variable_1 -> setField05               ($row['field_05']);
            $my_variable_1 -> setField06               ($row['field_06']);
            $my_variable_1 -> setField07               ($row['field_07']);
            $my_variable_1 -> setField08               ($row['field_08']);
            $my_variable_1 -> setField09               ($row['field_09']);
            $my_variable_1 -> setField10               ($row['field_10']);

            $my_variable_3 -> setField1                ($row['field_AA']);
            $my_variable_3 -> setField2                ($row['field_BB']);

            $my_variable_2 -> setField1                ($row['field_XX']);
            $my_variable_2 -> setField2                ($row['field_YY']);

            $text = "Creating ".$my_variable_1 -> getField1() ;
            $output->writeln( $text );

              $entityManager->persist($my_variable_1);
              $entityManager->persist($my_variable_3);
              $entityManager->persist($my_variable_2);
          }

          $entityManager -> flush();

    }
  // other loops like this
```

The fact is, I am always running out of memory. 
I have many loops like the one above, and each one is 10000+ long.
I tried extending the allowed memory size, but this is just postponing the problem.

Is there any good practice or coding method that would allow to keep the memory requirement low, or to free unused memory?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Just process data in smaller chunks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your problems lies most likely here:

..FROM mytable LIMIT ".$count*100 .", ".(++$count)*100)...

The MySQL `LIMIT` clause accepts two arguments. From documentation:

> With two arguments, the first argument specifies the offset of the first row to return, and the second specifies the maximum number of rows to return. The offset of the initial row is 0 (not 1):

In your case there is a linear progression, with every iteration you are selecting more and more records: *100, 200, 300,* etc.

Change that line of code to:

```
..FROM mytable LIMIT ".$count*100 .", "100...
```

You only need the offset to change, the second parameter indicating the max number of entries should remain unchanged.
This way with each iteration you will be selecting a maximum of 100 records and your memory problem should be solved.

**Update:**
Additionally make sure you detach the hydrated entities with each loop, to allow the GC to clean the memory.

***Example:***

```
$em->detach($entity);
```

More here: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/en/latest/reference/working-with-objects.html#detaching-entities

Comment: With original code you will also be getting large blocks of rows more that once.

Comment: I exploited this solution and managed to get it done. I thought it would run in a few hours, it took more than three days to complete. Additonal optimizations are required on my side, but this helped me to at least have a working solution.

Answer (score 1):

You are creating php objects in the entity manager which stay in the memory after they are persisted to the database. Try using the entity manager's clear() method to unset them.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately I cannot use clear() method since it wipes out ALL the persisted entities, while I need to keep a couple of them. However this would be useful for others in a similar situation.